# Name for a synchronous process that can buffer async tasks and then release

Tags: terminology

I have an async process that receives a message then post the content to another service and acknowledges the message.

To improve on the efficiency I want to batch the messages together, but can't request more than 1 message at a time from the external service.
Therefore I want to create a buffer in code to batch up the async threads and after X seconds, flush to another thread to perform the bulk action and then release the threads that have had their document sent so the thread can acknowledge the message in the broker.

I want to search for solutions to the buffer I wish to create but don't know the name of it.

Thanks for your help

[image: example of the process]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is or what you are hoping for in an answer.  It sounds like you have already described an approach to your situation that is quite reasonable.  What is your question?  What do you mean by "solutions to the buffer I wish to create"?

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of queueing mechanism?

Comment: I'm looking for is thr term for what I'm trying to do. So far I've found semaphores which is close but doesn't quite describe the case I'm trying to do  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)